# How to use Pyramid to host static files at an absolute path on my computer?

Tags: pyramid

I created a simple Pyramid app from the quick tutorial page [here](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/static_assets.html) that has the following files relevant to the question:

1. `tutorial/__init__.py`:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator


def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route('hello', '/howdy')
    config.add_static_view(name='static', path='tutorial:static')
    config.scan('.views')
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

2. `tutorial/views/views.py`:

```
from pyramid.view import (
    view_config,
    view_defaults
    )


@view_defaults(renderer='../templates/home.pt')
class TutorialViews:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(route_name='home')
    def home(self):
        return {'name': 'Home View'}

    @view_config(route_name='hello')
    def hello(self):
        return {'name': 'Hello View'}
```

3. `tutorial/templates/image.pt`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Quick Tutorial: ${name}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="${request.static_url('tutorial:static/app.css') }"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi ${name}</h1>
<img src="${filepath}">
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add a URL route to my app such that when a user goes to `www.foobar.com/{filename}` (for example: `www.foobar.com/test.jpeg`), the app would show the image from the absolute path `/Users/s/Downloads/${filename}`on the server, as shown in the file `tutorial/templates/image.pt` above.

This is what I tried:

- In the file `tutorial/__init__.py`, added `config.add_route('image', '/foo/{filename}')`.
- In the file `development.ini`, added the setting `image_dir = /Users/s/Downloads`.
- In the file `tutorial/views/views.py`, ddded the following view `image`:

```
@view_config(route_name='image', renderer='../templates/image.pt')
def image(request):
    import os
    filename = request.matchdict.get('filename')
    filepath = os.path.join(request.registry.settings['image_dir'], filename)
    return {'name': 'Hello View', 'filepath': filepath}
```

However this does not work. How can I get absolute paths for assets working with Pyramid?

Comment: I think I answered that in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63542264/2214933

Comment: @StevePiercy the problem with that is that I have two folders where I'm storing images, which is why I was trying to use URL pattern matching. Adding two static views won't work right? How can I use absolute paths and use two directories for image hosting?

Comment: I don't think you actually read my answer, where I said, "It is also OK to configure multiple static routes, if that is what you want."

Answer (score 0):

`filepath` needs to be a url if you're expecting to put it as the `src` attribute in an `img` tag in your HTML. The browser needs to request the asset. You should be doing something like `request.static_url(...)` or `request.route_url(...)` in that image tag. This is the URL generation part of the problem.

The second part is actually serving file contents when the client/browser requests that URL. You can use a static view to support mapping the folder on disk to a URL structure in your application in the same way as `add_static_view` is doing. There is a chapter on this in the Pyramid docs at https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/assets.html. There is also a section specifically on using absolute paths on disk. You can register multiple static views in your app if you feel it's necessary.